Definition of the value function in control theory
The following definition stems from the notes "An Introduction to Mathematical Optimal Control Theory" by Lawrence C. Evans (they are available online for free).
In defining the value function for a control theory problem $$\begin{cases} \dot{x} = f(x(s),\alpha(s)) \quad (t\leq s\leq T) \\ x(t) = x \end{cases}$$ with payoff functional $$P_{x,t}[\alpha(\cdot)] = \int_{t}^{T}r(x(s),\alpha(s))ds + g(x(T))$$ the value function is $$v(x,t) := \sup_{\alpha (\cdot) \in \mathcal{A}}P_{x,t}[\alpha(\cdot)] \quad (x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, 0\leq t \leq T)$$
Why would $$v(x,T) = g(x)\quad \text{instead of} \quad v(x,T) = g(x(T))$$

What is $g(x)$ supposed to be?

g represents the terminal payoff function

Because the value $v(x,t)$ represents the 'maximum' remaining payoff given that the state at time $t$ is $x$. Thus if at time $T$ you are in state $x$, you remaining payoff is by default just $g(x)$ since there is 'no more time left to act'.
